# Is pruning working in substrate?

Tags: pruning

I am running a `Polkadot-Node` and have tried `--state-pruning 256` and `--pruning=1000` but I keep seing 5,000 sst files one month old that should have removed.

256 or 1,000 blocks is less than one day so I should not see sst files from last month. Why is this?

I also see many old log txt files.

What is the correct way of setting the prunning in polkadot substrate node?

Is it safe to manually remove the old sst files?

Is it safe to manually remove the log txt files?

Thank you

Comment: are you able to access the old data on the explorer?

Comment: what explorer? I am just running a polkadot node and thought if using --prunning=1000 will just keep last 1,000 blocks in db but i dont understand why i still see records 1 month old.